# Razor @page enum parameter

Tags: c#, enums, razor-components

In Blazor (Razor components), is there a way to bind a page url parameter to an enum using the string value of the enum

```cs
@page "/index/{MyEnum}"

[Parameter]
public MyEnumType MyEnum { get; set; }
```

This seems to work while using the integer value of the enum, but it fails to cast the value if using the string.

```cs
@page "/index/{MyEnum:int}"

[Parameter]
public MyEnumType MyEnum { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to make it work with the string?

I've tried using `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` and `[EnumMember(Value = "myVal")]` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far is to bind to a string parameter and convert to enum using Enum.TryParse

```
@page "/index/{MyEnumString}"

private MyEnumType MyEnum { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string MyEnumString 
{ 
    get => MyEnum.ToString();
    set
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnumType>(value, true, out var enumValue))
        {
            MyEnum = enumValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The getter is useful if you intend to bind the value to other components.